# Join tables with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables: `cpu` and `cpubench`

`cpu` contains: `id, name, price`

`cpubench` contains: `name, mark, rank`

I want the `mark` from `cpubench` to be added to `cpu` in a new column rank if the names of both tables match.

I believe i should use Left Join

I found the following code

```
SELECT users.name AS user,
       products.name AS favorite
FROM users
LEFT JOIN products
ON users.fav = products.id
```

But I'm not sure how to do this, do I need to add a mark column to `cpu`?
Then how do I fill out the Left Join code.

Please explain as simply as possible please

Thanks

EDIT 1: i have gotten this far with my code
 `sql = ("SELECT cpu.id, cpu.name, cpu.price, cpubech.mark, FROM cpu LEFT JOIN cpubench ON cpu.name = cpubench.name")` 
however i get the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM cpu LEFT JOIN cpubench ON cpu.name = cpubench.name' at line 1

EDIT 2: I have fixed the syntax issues thanks Cid, however now no mark values are being matched all mark values in cpu are null even when i  have checked there is a mark in cpubench and that the names are identical see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMkMV.jpg

Comment: For 1 CPU, is there only 1 CPU bench? or can there be many CPU bench?

Comment: Is the query you provided from a unrelated project? Because the tables don't match. Can you provide an example of what _you_ have tried on your code?

Comment: And related to @Cid comment's, can it be the case where a cpu doesn't have any bench?

Comment: For each cpu there can only be 1 cpubench mark, however not all cpu have a matching cpubench mark

Comment: The code i just found from w3schools tutorial on doing left joins not sure how to substitute my tables in

Comment: should i add a mark column to cpu?

Comment: also it was rank not mark as previously stated, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Can you answer Cid's initial question please? Also what is the relation between the tables? It seems you store "name" in both, but that's not a good one to join on, because a) names can change and b) strings make poor search/indexing candidates and c) you're effectively duplicating meaningful data. It would be better to store the CPU ID in the bench table instead of the name, and that be the foreign key back to the CPU table. That is the normal practice in relational database design.

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results.

Comment: Also if the mark data already exists in bench, what's the point of duplicating it into the CPU table? (if that's even possible - if multiple benchmarks exist for one CPU you can't do it anyway). Just do a JOIN between the tables at the time you need to see all that info in a single place. That's kind of one of the main purposes of relational databases. Then again, if there's just a 1-to-1 mapping from cpu to bench, you don't need two tables in the first place.

Comment: ID does not exist in both tables i only have name

Comment: Yes but I'm saying you need to re-design it first so that you use the ID instead of the name. You're starting from a bad design, which is never a good place to start.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner https://imgur.com/a/JiHj7mx

Comment: @ADyson its the results from 2 scrapers that i want to combine so it is not an option

Comment: I see. Well then in order for anyone to give you an accurate answer, you need to answer Cid's question (see the very first comment). In fact better still, edit the question to provide some sample data and expected output. Please copy and paste some text data (so people can re-use it to test), not screenshots. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your query syntax is invalid (as stated the error message) : you have a comma in excess in the fields you're selecting

```
SELECT cpu.id, cpu.name, cpu.price, cpubech.mark, FROM ...
--        Remove this --------------------------^
```

Comment: Hi, thanks that fixed up the error! However nothing seems to be joining see example https://imgur.com/a/K86EPQE where AMD Ryzen 5 2600 is not matched even though the name is identical

Comment: is it because mark is an int on cpu and not cpubench?

Comment: I changed mark to VARCHAR(255) on both however after running join code mark is null on cpu?

Comment: using `VARCHAR` fields as referencing for a foreign key is a duplication of information. You don't want to repeat the name of the CPU in both table. I'd remove the `name` field in the `cpubech` and use a `FOREIGN KEY` referencing the cpu id instead

Comment: But how can I match 2 the 2 tables of I don't have a common factor of name between them, I can't use id as the tables are created from scrapers and only share name

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's a left join. For a join to execute properly, you will need similar columns in both tables. In your case you could map NAME in cpu to NAME in cpubench. You dont have to create a new column here. The code will automatically append the rank from cpubench to cpu to all the names that exist in both the tables. Hope that clears.

SELECT cpu.name AS a,
       cpubench.name AS b
FROM cpu
LEFT JOIN cpubench
ON a.name = b.name

Answer (score -1):

The quick-and-dirty answer to your question is

```
SELECT cpu.id, 
       cpu.name, 
       cpu.price, 
       cpubech.rank,
FROM cpu LEFT JOIN cpubench ON cpu.name = cpubench.name
```

You can add an alias to the columns with the `AS` keywork, if you want to change the names.

With this query you will get all the values on the `cpu` table, and for those that don't have a matching `cpubench` row you'll find `NULL` on the `rank` field.

Use `JOIN` (or `INNER JOIN`) to have only the CPUs with a matching benchmark.

As i side note, I would change the structure of your tables:

- if you need to keep the two tables, I would use `id` rather than `name` in `cpubench` as foreign key
- the relation between the two tables appears to be (0,1)-(1,1), where every bench has a cpu, but not the other way around. I would start thinking if it's a good idea to have just one table with both tables' data.

Comment: ok thanks so far i have: sql = SELECT cpu.id, 
             cpu.name, 
             cpu.price, 
             cpubech.mark,
FROM cpu LEFT JOIN cpubench ON cpu.name = cpubench.name

mycursor.execute(sql)